# minimising Longest-Path in DAG

Tags: algorithms, graphs, heuristics, dag

Assume we have **weighted** DAG (directed-acycle-graph), source **s** and target **t**.

Define the number of edges as $E$.

Given $0<\alpha<1$:

Choose $\alpha*E$ edges *to cut their weight* by half so that the longest path from **s** to **t** is minimized.

Personal note:
We've been asked this question by our professor.
I assume the problem is NP-Hard. We are looking for some heuristics that will gives us good results, not necessarily optimal.

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: (Seems to "prefer" paths with not much more than $\alpha\times E$ costly edges.)

Comment: What do you meet by that @greybeard? You have no control over the initial longest-paths

Comment: It's just a musing about what difference $\alpha$ makes. Between paths with less than $\alpha\times E$ edges with weight>0: none. Path with most costly $\alpha\times E$ edges contributing less than half the cost: cost after halving greater than three quarters of the original.